# How to do sink plumbing in the basement?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain

We are working on finishing our basement. We have this area that is perfect for a fridge/counter and maybe a sink.

[image]

I'm thinking of leaving space for a fridge on the left, then some cabinet/countertop. Then some overhead cabinets as well.

We are thinking of installing a small sink but I'm questioning how to get a sink to drain due to the positioning of the plumbing. Would we have to get some sort of pump to push the water out?

The pipe pictured overhead comes from the kitchen upstairs.
[image]

Then leads to this outlet here that is at least 2 feet from the ground.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your last pic seems to indicate where the drain exits to the street/septic system. If your sink bowl is enough above that point that you can run a drain line from the sink, with the proper 1/4" per foot slope, and tie it into this drain, you should be fine. If not, then you'll need some sort of lift pump to get the waste water up to that level.

If you're going to end up going with the lift pump, you might consider putting in a bathroom nearby to get more use out of the pump.

Comment: In the second picture on the right-hand side you can see a cavity that is meant for a gas fireplace, So trying to tie-in to that main outlet might be out of the question. There is a bathroom, but it's further away.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's what, but I'll trust you. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might need an ejector pump.  My shop is part of my house, but with a garage inbtween. The floor of the shop/garage is slab on grade (of course), so no crawl to run plumbing. There is a small sink in the shop that needed supply and drain.  Used an ejector pump to run the drain up into the attic.

There are many kinds, so if you need it, you'll have to do some shopping.  Don't confuse a sump pump with an ejector pump, they are very different.